# How to click on the Span class element

Tags: java, html, testing, selenium, automation

I need to find the HTML code for the editor.

```
<span class="td-creative-name"></span>

<div class="editors pull-right" style="visibility: visible;">

    <ul id="editorList">
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li>
            <span class="dc-url omedia-link" title="" data-placement="top" rel="tooltip" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Creative URL"></span>
        </li>
        <li></li>
    </ul>
```

I would like to click on the "Creative URL" here.  Can you please help me with the code?  I am unable to make it work.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/XWzke/

Comment: http://sauceio.com/index.php/2011/03/the-selenium-click-command/

Comment: Could you also post, besides the HTML you've already posted, the selenium code that you've tried so far?  I'm curious as to whether you are using the old selenium, or Selenium 2 (WebDriver).

Comment: Hi, I've tried this java code. 
WebDriverWait wait3 = new WebDriverWait(wd, 300);
  wait3.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[contains(@class,'dc-url omedia-link')]")));
      wd.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(@class,'dc-url omedia-link')]")).click(); But this is not doing any action. can you please help making it work.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code using jquery put id in the span

```
$("#myspan").click(function(){
alert('I got a click');
});
```

Thanks 
Maha

Comment: Hi, I've tried this java code. 
WebDriverWait wait3 = new WebDriverWait(wd, 300);
  wait3.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[contains(@class,'dc-url omedia-link')]")));
      wd.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(@class,'dc-url omedia-link')]")).click(); But this is not doing any action. can you please help making it work.

Answer (score 0):

The HTML `<span>` element has an `onclick` attribute which you can use. For an example, see the following jfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tpHr3/1/.

In your case, you want to fill in the `onclick` attribute of your `span` tag:

```
<span class="dc-url omedia-link" title="" 
      data-placement="top" rel="tooltip" 
      data toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Creative URL" 
      onclick="yourFunction();"></span>
```

Comment: Hi, I've tried this java code. 
WebDriverWait wait3 = new WebDriverWait(wd, 300);
  wait3.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[contains(@class,'dc-url omedia-link')]")));
      wd.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(@class,'dc-url omedia-link')]")).click(); But this is not doing any action. can you please help making it work.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/XWzke/

```
$("#editorList li span").click(function(){
    alert('clicked');
});
```

Comment: Hi, I've tried this java code. 
WebDriverWait wait3 = new WebDriverWait(wd, 300);
  wait3.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[contains(@class,'dc-url omedia-link')]")));
      wd.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(@class,'dc-url omedia-link')]")).click(); But this is not doing any action. can you please help making it work.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using selenium, then you can find the element and click on it,

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='dc-url omedia-link')]")).click();
```

Note: if the xpath I mentioned doesn't work go for css selector or any other.

Comment: Hi, I've tried this java code. 
WebDriverWait wait3 = new WebDriverWait(wd, 300);
  wait3.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[contains(@class,'dc-url omedia-link')]")));
      wd.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(@class,'dc-url omedia-link')]")).click(); But this is not doing any action. can you please help making it work.

Comment: @AutoMationBegginer is the element present? does your wait fails? Use visibilityOfElementLocated instead of presenceOfElementLocated and try.

Comment: It does not work. It doesnt do any action and also doesnt throw any error.. any ideas

Comment: @AutoMationBegginer Check the element is present or not by using isDisplayed/ using size() if it is not displayed, or it is in someother frame, etc